# IceJoomla - > icebooking -> Email sending Form. Where is this file located?

Tags: php, forms, email, joomla

I am working with Icejoomla Icebooking files manual configuration for one website. I made additional form-field "car parking" and it works fine. The DataBase updates itself fine, email sended to customer also included with that information. But the email form is somehow different as it should be - some fields there are not in place.
Maybe someone knows in which directory i should search for the files to edit the email form? Or in which directory admin inputs the email-form data? There are more than 26000 files so i spent about 4 hours and didnt find yet :)

Comment: Found all, now all works fine :)

Comment: You could add the solution to an answer and mark it as solved for future reference.